# Showing a point is a saddle point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that if $x'=(x,y) \ \  $ is a critical point of a $\mathcal{C}^3$ function $f$ such that: $$f_{xx}(x')f_{yy}(x')-(f_{xy}(x'))^2<0$$

Then there are points $x$ and $z$ near $x'$ such that $f(x)>f(x') \ \ $ and $\ \ f(z)<f(x')$

I know that since  $f_{xx}(x')f_{yy}(x')-(f_{xy}(x'))^2<0 \ \ $ there is a saddle point at that location, but I'm not sure how I could show that in a more formal proof or more formal explanation.  Thanks in advance and sorry if there's bad formatting.

Comment: I edited your question, tell me if it's all ok

Comment: @rlartiga its much better thanks!

Comment: Maybe Taylor could be a good friend

Comment: @rlartiga different definition of friend for us, I'll see if I could apply Taylor anywhere though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=f(x')+\nabla(x')\cdot (x-x')+\frac{1}{2}(x-x')^T H(x')(x-x') + R_3(x) $$

Where $R_3$ is the a function which tends to $0$ when $x \to x'$

How $x'$ is a critic point $\nabla(x')=0 \ $  so:

$$f(x)=f(x')+\frac{1}{2}(x-x')^T H(x')(x-x') $$
$$f(x)-f(x')=\frac{1}{2}(x-x')^T H(x')(x-x') $$

How $H(x')$ is indefinite (that's your hypothesis) exists $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that

$$x_1^T H x_1>0>x_2^T H x_2$$

Take $x_3=x'+x_1$:

$$f(x_3)-f(x')=\frac{1}{2}(x_3-x')^T H(x')(x_3-x')=\frac{1}{2}x_1^T H(x')x_1>0$$

Finally take $x_4=x'+x_2$:

$$f(x_4)-f(x')=\frac{1}{2}(x_4-x')^T H(x')(x_4-x')=\frac{1}{2}x_2^T H(x')x_2<0$$

Comment: this looks really good!  I'll probably be trying it out within the hour, thanks a lot I really appreciate it, this makes a lot of sense

Comment: I still don't get it to continue the question, honestly I never learnt about hessians or Aigen values and I'm still in a class using them so this question is really difficult for me.  I follow up to what you've done, I just can't think of it.

Comment: @Anthony I completed the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: it helps a lot I really appreciate it